# minitoc does not work with \RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter} in KOMA-Script

Tags: scrbook, minitoc

Up to now I always found a solution on this site, but today is the day to ask a question that has not been discussed afaik:

I am changing from book document class to scrbook, trying to solve an issue with minitoc:

This MWE works just fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
    \dominitoc[n]
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \minitoc

    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: working MWE output]

Now I want to shift the chapter line upwards with

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{chapter}
```

Adding this to the MWE will cause the minitoc not to be printed:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{chapter}

\begin{document}
    \dominitoc[n]
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \minitoc

    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: no minitoc created]
By the way, the chapter title is shifted up as desired.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}` before loading `minitoc`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{chapter}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc[n]
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\minitoc
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```