# How to write a minitoc with plain KOMA-script?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, incompatibility, minitoc

External packages for minitoc's are incompatible with KOMA-script.
There are workarounds ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400587/minitoc-does-not-work-with-redeclaresectioncommandchapter-in-koma-script)), ([2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430594/use-minitoc-with-koma-script-scrbook)) but a workaround sometimes calls for trouble at the next update.

How can I generate a **main table of contents** plus a 
**table of contents per chapter** without additional packages in plain KOMA?

Comment: You can adapt the answer of @Schweinebacke to [Create section-level toc in a KOMA-script document that already uses minitoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758/43317) for chapter tocs.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a suggestion that adapts the answer of @Schweinebacke to [Create section-level toc in a KOMA-script document that already uses minitoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758/43317) for chapter tocs.

It uses package `scrwfile` to avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles. Additionally I have added an optional argument for the postfix of the file extension. So it can be used for `\addchap` too.

```latex
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifusechaptertoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[1][\thechapter]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \usechaptertoctrue% switch on chapter-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@subtoc{toc#1}% extension of the section-toc-file, e.g., toc1
  \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@subtoc}% declare a new toc file
  \addsec*{Contents}% header of the chaptertoc
  \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
    \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
    \listoftoc*{\ext@subtoc}% show the toc without header
  \end{minipage}\par
  \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusechaptertoc% if chapter toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@subtoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% automatically switch of chapter toc entries at start of every \chapter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{Introduction}
\chaptertoc[Intro]
\blindtext
\addsec{Unnumbered I}
\Blindtext
\addsec{Unnumbered II}
\blindtext

\chapter{one}
\chaptertoc
\blindtext
\section{two}\Blindtext
\section{three}\blindtext
\subsection{four}\Blindtext
\subsection{five}\blindtext
\section{six}\blindtext

\chapter{seven}
\chaptertoc
\section{eight}\Blindtext
\section{nine}\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the `.toc` file generated by KOMA-Script and divide it up by chapters.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}

% Works with or without hyperref.
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  % Macros for resetting and appending to the variables that store the chapter tocs.
  \def\@chaptoc@toc@reset{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @chaptoc@toc@\@chaptoc@chapter@num\endcsname{}%
  }
  \def\@chaptoc@toc@append{%
    \expandafter\gappto\csname @chaptoc@toc@\@chaptoc@chapter@num\endcsname
  }
  % The parsing macro, that goes through the toc file and creates the chapter toc macros.
  \def\@chaptoc@parse@tocfile{%
    % We only need to do this once.
    \let\@chapter@parse@tocfile\relax
    \begingroup
      \def\@chaptoc@chapter@num{0}%
      \@chaptoc@toc@reset
      \makeatletter
      \IfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{%
        \CatchFileDef\@tmpa{\jobname.toc}{}%
        \expandafter\@chaptoc@parse@head
        \@tmpa
        \contentsline\@chaptoc@parse@stop%
      }{}%
    \endgroup
  }
  \def\@chaptoc@chapter@string{chapter}
  \def\@chaptoc@parse@stop{\@chaptoc@parse@stop}%
  \long\def\@chaptoc@parse@head#1\contentsline#2{%
    \@chaptoc@toc@append{#1}%
    \ifx\@chaptoc@parse@stop#2%
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \begingroup
      \def\@tmpa{#2}%
      \ifx\@tmpa\@chaptoc@chapter@string
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\@chaptoc@parse@cline@chapter
      \else
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\@chaptoc@parse@cline@other
      \fi
    \fi
    {#2}%
  }
  \def\@chaptoc@parse@cline@other{%
    \@chaptoc@toc@append{\contentsline}%
    \@chaptoc@parse@head
  }
  \def\@chaptoc@parse@cline@chapter#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1##2\@nil{%
        \endgroup
        \def\@chaptoc@chapter@num{##1}%
      }%
    #2\@nil
    \@chaptoc@toc@reset
    \expandafter\@chaptoc@parse@head\@chaptoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs
  }
  % A macro for printing the current chapter toc.
  \def\@chaptoc@toc@print{%
    \begingroup
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{\chaptocdepth}%
      \parindent 0pt%
      \section*{\contentsname}%
      \csname @chaptoc@toc@\arabic{chapter}\endcsname
      \@chaptoc@toc@afterhook
    \endgroup
  }
  \newcommand*\chaptocdepth{\value{tocdepth}}
  \def\@chaptoc@toc@afterhook{}
  \newcommand\chaptocafter[1]{%
    \def\@chaptoc@toc@afterhook{#1}%
  }
  % Set everything up.
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    % When hyperref is loaded, \contentsline has one more argument.
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\let\protect\@chaptoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs\protect\@gobble}%
    }{%
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\let\protect\@chaptoc@parse@gobble@hyperrefargs\protect\@empty}%
    }%
    % When the aux file is read in the first time, the toc file will be parsed.
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \protect\@chaptoc@parse@tocfile
    }%
    % Automatically print the chapter toc after each chapter title.
    \apptocmd\scr@@startchapter{\@chaptoc@toc@print}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\subsection{four}
\subsection{five}
\section{six}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\chapter{seven}
\section{eight}
\section{nine}

\chapter{ten}
\section{eleven}
\subsection{twelve}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \vskip\protect\baselineskip\hrule\vskip\protect\baselineskip
  This line was manually added!%
  \vskip\protect\baselineskip\hrule\vskip\protect\baselineskip
}
\subsection{thirteen}
\section{fourteen}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

- I use [`catchfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) to save the content of the `.toc` file in a macro before parsing it. This way I can easily insert parsing macros right before and after the `.toc` content.
- Discontinuous chapter numbering and manually inserted code are supported. (Though you can certainly break it if you try.)
- `hyperref` is supported
- By default, the chapter tocs have the same depth as the main toc, but you can change that by redefining `\chaptocdepth`.
- By default, nothing is added after the chapter toc, but you can change that using `\chaptocafter`. Reasonable options could be, for example, `\chaptocafter{\section*{}}`, `\chaptertocafter{\clearpage}` or some `\vskip`, depending on your document.